# start "unrelated" 64 bit app from 32 bit app

Tags: c, fork

is there an elegant way to start a 64 bit process from an 32 bit compiled application?

The problem is that i need to compile one part in 32bit Sparc V8 mode. The other part is written for a faster 64 bit environment (no emulation on 64bit multiplication). I want to synchronize them using semaphore and communicate via shared memory.

Man pages for fork, system etc. show that the parent process gets suspended until the child process terminates. Is there a better way to do so because i dont want to start the processes manually.

best regard
Bernhard

Comment: fork() does not suspend parent process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use fork() then exec().  Generally multi-process stuff remains the same even in a mixed environment.